# How to invert factor.levels of learner in R (mlr), so the output is the same order between different questions

Tags: r, mlr

thank you for supporting me with my question!
I'm running the code for different questions (e.g "Yellow"/"notYellow", "Blue"/"NotBlue"...). In the end I would like to sum up the data of "proben" in one Excel sheet. Unfortunately the confusionmatrix and the order of the columns "prob.notColour" and "prob.Colour" differ between the different questions. This is because of the different order of the factor.levels I guess. But changing those manually to a vector the right order:

```
learner.train$factor.levels <- c("Yellow", "notYellow")
```

does not help. As well as changing the input of positive to the task:

```
task.colours <- makeClassifTask (colours, target= "Colour", positive = "notYellow"
task.proben <- makeClassifTask(colours.probe, target = "Colour", positive ="notYellow")
```

I was not able to find a solution for this or areason why R does this. I would be so thankful if anyone has a suggestion! Thank you in advance :)

The below code is just an example of my original code, so please excuse typos

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

proben <- c("p11","p35")

colours <- Col %>%
drop_na(colour) %>% 
mutate(colour = case_when(colour == 'Yellow' ~ 'Yellow', TRUE ~ 'notYellow'))
  
colours.probe <- colours %>% filter(Nr %in% proben)

colours <- colours %>%
filter(!Nr %in% proben)

task.colours <- makeClassifTask(colours, target = "Colour",  positive = "Yellow")
task.proben <- makeClassifTask(colours.probe, target = "Colour")
learner <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest", ntree = 1000, sampsize = c(80,80), predict.type = "prob", mtry = 54, nodesize = 7)
learner.train <- train(learner, task.colours)

#learner.train$factor.levels ($Colour "notYellow", "Yellow")

task.colours.pred <- predict(learner.train, task.colours)
task.proben.pred <- predict(learner.train, task.proben)

matrix1 <- calculateConfusionMatrix(task.colours.pred, relative = T)
matrix3 <- task.proben.pred$data %>% add_column(proben, .before = T)

#Export to Excel
```

As @LarsKotthoff asked for I tried to reproduce the inverted factor with the iris data set:

```
library(mlr) 
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

data <- iris
data <- tibble::rowid_to_column(data, "ID")

proben <- c("1", "50", "100")

#Binary classification problem with Setosa against others
data.setosa <- data %>%
  mutate(Species = case_when(Species=="setosa"~"Setosa", TRUE~"notSetosa"))

setosa.probe <- data.setosa %>% filter (ID %in% proben)

data.setosa <- data.setosa %>% filter(!ID %in% proben)

task.setosa <- makeClassifTask("Setosa",data.setosa, target ="Species", positive = "Setosa")
task.proben <- makeClassifTask("Proben",setosa.probe, target = "Species")
learner.lda <- makeLearner("classif.lda", predict.type = "prob")
learner.train.setosa <- train(learner.lda, task.setosa)

learner.train.setosa$factor.levels
#Output: $Species; "notSetosa" "Setosa"

#Binary classification problem with versicolor against others
data.versicolor <- data %>%
  mutate(Species = case_when(Species=="versicolor"~"Versicolor", TRUE~"notVersicolor"))

versicolor.probe <- data.versicolor %>% filter (ID %in% proben)

data.versicolor <- data.versicolor %>% filter(!ID %in% proben)

task.versicolor <- makeClassifTask("Versicolor",data.versicolor, target ="Species", positive = "Versicolor")
task.proben <- makeClassifTask("Proben",versicolor.probe, target = "Species")
learner.lda <- makeLearner("classif.lda", predict.type = "prob")
learner.train.versicolor <- train(learner.lda, task.versicolor)

learner.train.versicolor$factor.levels
#Output: $Species; "notVersicolor" "Versicolor"
```

unfortunatley all three Outputs are ordered the same. May it be a problem with the dataset then? Is there stil an option to change the order of the factor.levels?

Comment: If you want to reorder levels, try relevel() function.

Comment: @Park I tried, but it says:
Error in relevel.default(silvaner.train.rf$factor.levels) : 'relevel' only for (unordered) factors

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I did so, but unfortunately (as wirtten in the question) not capable to reproduce the invert problem...

Comment: The reason is because the `n` in `not` comes before `S` in `setosa` and `V` in `versicolor`. Probably you should consider including a digit or underscore as they are all less than alphabets. In your data, use `0notYellow`, `0notBlue` or even `_notYellow`, `_notBlue`. The zero will just help in ordering. Once you are completely done with your work, you can then remove it

Answer (score 0):

The question : "Is there stil an option to change the order of the factor.levels?" has always been and repeatedly answered on SO. Use the `levels` parameter of the `factor` function. Here's an example that shows how to set an "ordering" for a non-ordered factor:

```
> fac10 <- factor(1:10)
> levels(fac10) <- sample(fac10)
> fac10
 [1] 4  10 7  5  3  1  9  6  8  2 
Levels: 4 10 7 5 3 1 9 6 8 2
```

Factors are integers into a lookup table of character levels. The integer ordering is used by many plotting and regression functions, so the character level associated with 1 is the first item in the factor. (In the example above, the integer values. The integer values remain an ascendign integer sequence. The numeric underpinnings for the example above were:

```
 as.numeric(fac10)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

The fact that factors are printed in R without the quotes that would normally surround character values leads to many errors in assuming that data that was supposed to be numeric and appears numeric at the top of a data.frame is in point of fact a factor. This is typical in transfers from Excel when errors are character type after conversion to .csv files.

(I have no idea regarding your example because it doesn't run. You must have a different iris dataset.)